# Transform list of dictionaries into dict of dicts

Tags: python

What is the easiest way to transform this list of dictionaries:

```
[
  {'code': 1, name:'A', value:'1'},
  {'code': 1, name:'B', value:'2'},
  {'code': 2, name:'C', value:'3'},
  {'code': 2, name:'D', value:'4'},
  {'code': 3, name:'E', value:'5'},
  {'code': 3, name:'F', value:'6'},
  ......
]
```

into this:

```
{
   1: [{name:'A', value:'1'}, {name:'B', value:'2'}],
   2: [{name:'C', value:'3'}, {name:'D', value:'4'}],
   3: [{name:'E', value:'5'}, {name:'F', value:'6'}],
   ...
}
```

I would like a nice solution like list comprehension, not the hard way.
Thanks

Comment: Since you know what a list comprehension is, try playing with a dict comprehension for a while and see what that gets you

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension would require an (inefficient) sorting operation, then grouping.

It's much easier to use a dictionary and a loop:

```
res = {}
for entry in inputlist:
    code = entry.pop('code')
    res.setdefault(code, []).append(entry)
```

This *alters* the original dictionaries; create a copy first if this is an issue:

```
entry = dict(entry)
code = entry.pop('code')
```

If your input list is *already* sorted, then you could use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to produce the dictionary in a one-liner, but the readability of this solution is debatable:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

res = {key: [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k != 'code'} for d in group]
       for key, group in groupby(inputlist, itemgetter('code'))}
```

Comment: my mind got blowed away. how is it possible. how can u write such easy code great! :) and +1

Comment: I am retrieving the data from the DB, I don't need to sort it. But seems good for the power of learning

Comment: @Martijin Pieters and, additionally, how to sort res by keys? (i.e. by code)

Comment: @MihaiZamfir: `res` is a *dictionary*; dictionaries have no ordering.

Comment: @Martijin Pieters I thought there is a way to sort it without taking the keys, sort them and then taking `res[key]`...

Comment: What output did you expect? A list of key-value pairs? Just the values?

Comment: @Martijin PIeters Exactly the output stated in the initial post. And, as you can see, they are sorted by the value of `code`

Comment: That's not possible. Dictionaries have no order. You'd have to use a `OrderedDict` instead, or just sort the keys as you loop over the keys.